# there is no package called ‘fansi’

Tags: r

My codes were：

```r
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
```

Then:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘fansi’
```

Any genius can help me figure out a solution?

Comment: Maybe install the `fansi` package?

Comment: Some packages require other packages in order to work. According to the error message, you need to install the package 'fansi' in order to get devtools installed.

Comment: Take a look at the `install.packages()` command

Comment: Usually installing ```devtools``` also installs all dependencies, but maybe there was an issue installing ```fansi```. Try installing ```fanci```, as already said, then reinstall ```devtools```

Comment: Problems like this can occur if/when a package (or one of its dep packages) cannot be installed in-place (e.g., when a package is being used, re-installing/updating may not work). This often leaves the package in an unusable state for future R sessions (and other packages). I recommend: closing and restarting your R session completely (no `.Rdata`); `install.packages("fansi")` (as @G5W suggested); and then finally `install.packages("devtools")`.